# critical to ensuring or to ensure?

Tags: grammar

> People power is **critical to ensuring** that hardware, software, and connectivity are effectively integrated in a society responsible way.

why ing from has been used here? it could be "critical to ensure"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also say something is "critical to ensure".  These are two different ways to say the same thing.

The -ing form is a gerund, which in this case is the first word in a *[gerund phrase](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/)* that acts like a noun.  Meanwhile, "to ensure" is the *infinitive* form, which also acts like a noun.

Here's another example:

> The first instruction is **making sure** the power is turned off.

This is a basic "Noun A is Noun B" sentence, like "I am an American".  You could also say this same sentence as:

> The first instruction is **to make sure** the power is turned off.

Same thing, different form.  A third way to say this would be:

> The first instruction says we **should make sure** the power is turned off.

Sometime one form sounds better than the other, but both are grammatically correct.

Comment: According to Google, "critical to ensuring" should be also right.

Comment: after "to" we must use "ensure" otherwise it is not correct grammatically, could you please explain more? you mean after "critical to" I always have to use a noun?

Comment: @Stefano  "to" is just a preposition.  There is no rule that after "to" you have to use a verb -- that's just a simple guide that you may have been taught to help you learn about simple English sentence structures.  "To" can be followed by many things, depending on what is idiomatic.

Comment: @Stefano  The only way to learn this is to read what native speakers write, and then copy those structures in your own writing.  Sometimes you'll read something that sounds strange, but you won't know if it's because it's wrong, or because it's just poor writing style.

Comment: completely understand.  thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically speaking, "to" can be a particle forming part of the infinitive or a preposition followed by a gerund (V-ing).

In this case, both can be used, though with a slight difference in meaning.

"*to* + infinitive" has a purpose reading. Therefore:

a. People power is critical to ensure that hardware, software, and connectivity are effectively integrated in a socially responsible way. (I guess you meant to say "socially" rather than "society".)

is similar to saying:

- People power is critical **in order to ensure / for the purpose of ensuring** that hardware, software, and connectivity are effectively integrated in a socially responsible way.

Instead, "*to* + V-ing" conveys a metaphorical direction meaning:

b. People power is critical to ensuring that hardware, software, and connectivity are effectively integrated in a socially responsible way.

Here, the gerund phrase starting with "ensuring" is the object to which the criticality of people power is directed. I know this is a bit too abstract, but let me try to explain it with other adjectives that also accept both patterns:

c. Such parental attitudes can be helpful or harmful to educate children.

d. Such parental attitudes can be helpful or harmful to educating children.

While (c) indicates purpose, "educating children" sounds like "children's education", so (d) implies that children's education can be facilitated or harmed by certain parental attitudes. The preposition "to" introduces an object, while "*to* + infinitive" introduces a purpose. Although the final meaning of (c) and (d) ends up being similar, there is a slight difference, just as there is between (a) and (b).